# "Не оправдал возложенного высокого доверия"

Tags: фразеология

Вчера мне сказали, что "не оправдала возложенного высокого доверия". Не то, чтобы слышу в первый раз (довольно часто), но почему доверие "высокое"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имеется в виду доверие высокопоставленного лица. "Высочайшее доверие" — доверие от царственной особы.

Comment: А как правильно: "не оправдал возложенное высокое доверие" или "не оправдал возложенного высокого доверия"?

Comment: Как известно, глагол с частицей НЕ требует, чтобы управляемое слово стояло в родительном падеже. Это относится к управляемым словам, обозначающим отвлеченные понятия: не оправдал доверия, не имеет права, не вызывает сомнений, НО не вижу стол, не читаю книги (хотя возможно "не читаю книг")